# How to create div one after the another in a web page

Tags: css, html, responsive

I want to make a website with div one below the another .How do i set the height of the responsive page .There is no content inside div .I want to make solid border rectangle .This is for practise purpose.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #906aaf
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #7e599e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0
}

.one {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.three {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.four {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.five {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
```

Comment: flex box or css grid is probably what you want to really use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to position the first div in the html to show on the web page AFTER those that come next in the html -

You can use css3 flexbox. Apply the `display:flex` on the `body` and then use `order` on the `body`'s children to order them.

So in your example, add this to your css -

```
body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column; //(Flexbox defaults to row, apply this to change back to column)
}
.one {
      order: 5;
}
.two {
      order: 1;
} ...
```

Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

use pixel instead of %

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:800px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  background: #906aaf
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #7e599e;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0
}

.one {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.two {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.three {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.four {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.five {
  width: 50%;
  height: 240px;
  border: 10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="five"></div>
```

Comment: Contrary to what this answer suggests, pixels are almost certainly NOT the way to go here if you want to be responsive. I would suggest suggest vh units, which are a percentage of the viewport, instead.

Comment: This probably isn't a good approach from the perspective of responsive design.